# writing in child process c++

Tags: c++, process, fork, parent

I am trying to change a variable value inside a child process and keep it for the rest of the program. So In the below example why my cout keeps printing 0, and how do I solve it?

```
int var = 0;
int pid = fork();

if (pid == 0){ //child process
   var = 1;
   exit(1);
}
else if (pid> 0){  //parent process
         if (-1 == wait (0))
              perror ("there was an error with wait");
}

cout << var;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how code execution is going to go.

**Child Process**

```cpp
int var =0;

var = 1;
exit (1);
```

**Parent Process**

```cpp
int var =0;
if (-1 == wait (0))
  perror ("there was an error with wait);

cout << var;
```

So as you can see, `var` will not be changed for the parent process.

When you `fork`, the child and parent have separate copies of the variables that were present before they split off into execution paths. **Processes do not share the same block of memory.** Therefore, altering `var` for the child will not affect the `var` in the parent.

If you want multiple execution paths on the **same** piece of memory, you should use **threads**.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the fork() call has failed. Check the errno value

RETURN VALUE
On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child. On failure, -1 is returned in the parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

ERRORS
EAGAIN
fork() cannot allocate sufficient memory to copy the parent's page tables and allocate a task structure for the child.
EAGAIN
It was not possible to create a new process because the caller's RLIMIT_NPROC resource limit was encountered. To exceed this limit, the process must have either the CAP_SYS_ADMIN or the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability.
ENOMEM
fork() failed to allocate the necessary kernel structures because memory is tight.

CONFORMING TO SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001.